# Excel datavalidation list separator

Tags: excel, separator, validation, vba

I have datavalidation on list

I need First entry will be "Enter Value" and separate this entry from other list items by inserting blank row or line, as it will be like selectable header entry. Separator must be not selectable when walking trought the list

Something like that

```
Enter value

Item1
Item2
Item2

or

Enter value
------------
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

Without using COMBOBOXes please!!!

Comment: Anything in a data validation list is selectable. Why do you need a header rather than using the Input message?

Comment: As I need quickly filling posibility.

Comment: If you don't want a Combo, where you want to keep the data ? the list are shown latereally?

Comment: I can do combo because code is already writed by other person and change datavalidation to combo is equal write new code as much of cells is dependent on this datavalidation list

Answer (score 1):

The best you can probably do is add those two new values to the list, then catch when invalid values are selected with the Worksheet_Change event. For example, when A1 has the validation list:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("A1") = "Enter value" Or Range("A1") = "______" Then
    MsgBox ("OMG! Even though the value is selectable, you may not select it. Select something else please.")
    Range("A1") = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Problem is that this value are selectable and takes times to click every time down arrow key twice

Comment: I don't think there's any way around that, as far as I know. Sorry. It's better to use the validation list's input message for this kind of thing.